# Why my action bar is resizing itself?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I am using `toolbar` as my `support action bar` inside an `Action Bar Activity` which consists of a `View Pager` with 4 tabs to scroll by in which i am facing an strange issue. This activity launches after the user has logged in. When i have logged in my app very first time then there isn't any issue. But when i start the app second time the toolbars top most part is hidden & then it starts sliding from top & fit inside activity layout below system bar. 
Below is the screen shot attached.[image]

Below is my xml layout code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomTabBar">

        </FrameLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomTabBar"
            layout="@layout/bottom_tab_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawerContent"
        layout="@layout/drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone knows about the issue or someone suggest that what i am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your parent layout or set it in your theme to effect globally in your `style.xml` `apptheme`

`<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`

Comment: i have already tried with that but it's not affecting the issue.

Comment: @AshishKumarGupta then add this attribute to your parent view and try . `android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: How padding works for that? It will create a blank space above my toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Make this attribute of the parent layout to false

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

**True**: if its true then the layout is gets merged with status bar.

**False**: If its false, then layout is drawn below status bar.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomTabBar">

    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomTabBar"
        layout="@layout/bottom_tab_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/drawerContent"
    layout="@layout/drawer_content"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't make any change?

Comment: No, try this it will work. If possible please show us xml code.

Comment: i have edited the question, please check the xml code of my activity.

Comment: Okay, Change ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity